# MongoDB group from empty array returns nothing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose(Node.js) and I have to group the results of match in aggregation.
Like,

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
      $match: {
          type: 1
      }
  },
  {
    $group : {
       _id : null,
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

If there are 10 items matched, then the result would be

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "count": 10
  }
]
```

Surely, if none of them are matched, I expect the result to be

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

However, I got the following result for this case.

```
[]
```

What should I do if I want to get the result as I expected?
Thank you for your kind help in advance.

Comment: This is just how the library behaves. You can't really alter its behavior unless you modify the source.

Comment: I understand how it behaves. But I want to know the way I can get that result with some manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't need an `aggregate`, you could use a simple `count` to count the matched items:

```
db.collection.count({
     type: 1
});
```

It always returns something, for example `0` if there is not match.

Comment: But I have to use aggregate for the further purpose.

Comment: You haven't specify that in your question

Comment: Sorry about that. This aggregation is the only part of my whole aggregation and I can't use it because of this part.

Comment: Then the best aproach is to take that no-matching case into account at the application level as opposed to database level

Comment: Yes, I guess that is the best solution. I was just wondering there is a way to deal with it at the database level. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should group by something (_id shouldn't be null). Try something like:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
      $match: {
          type: 1
      }
  },
  {
    $group : {
       _id : "$type",
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: A group by null groups everything, so it's valid as long as that's what's intended.